# Stopping setInterval

Tags: javascript

I am playing around with "ID's" trying to get comfortable and such. I know jQuery has a really quick solution, but I want to know how to do it via js.

```
     var startTimer = function init(){
                var n = 0;
                var e = document.getElementById("output");
                var myTimer = setInterval (function() {e.innerHTML = n++;},100);
                // clearInterval(myTimer);
                if(myTimer === 10){
                    clearInterval(myTimer);
                    return;

                }
            }                  

           startTimer();
```

Comment: Why do you compare your timer's id with `10`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you actually want this?

```
function initTimer(){
    var n = 0;
    var e = document.getElementById("output");
    var timerid = setInterval( function() {
        e.innerHTML = n;
        if (n < 10) // count until ten
            n++;
        else
            clearInterval(timerid); // this happens somewhen later
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much!
So you set the setInterval function as a var so you could clear it  later w/the clearInterval(in the else); and is the anonymous function being used as a param in the setInterval function?

Comment: On setting/clearing intervals, you might read [those](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) [references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval)

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing myTimer to 10, you should compare n instead:

```
if(n===10) ...
```

Comment: Changing only that would not help